# Catch MailException

Tags: email, playframework

Is it possible to catch a MailException when sending an e-mail?
I want to catch it in scenarios like mail server is down, malformed e-mail address, etc.

I see the MailException in the console but I cannot catch it when I call `Mailer.send()`. The `Mailer.send()` sends the e-mail asynchronously and thus I cannot catch the exception. How can I wait for the result suspending the HTTP request?

Another question: Does the `Mailer.sendAndWait()` suspend the request?

Answer (score 0):

First the mail() method might throw a MailException if sending mail fails.

The send methods return a Future of type Boolean, if you call get() on the future you will get the result of the mail sending, mind that this call is blocking and will wait for the mail sending to finish.
This is the same thing as using sendAndWait()

This get can also throw an ExecutionException but I don't have the impression this is used by the play mailer. Instead you get back false from the future and the exception is logged.

SendAndWait() does not suspend the request as far as I can see in the sources

more info here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Mailer.java
https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/Mail.java

Comment: In fact it would be cleaner if the mail's Future get() method would throw a ExecutionException pointing to the original exception